# Вопрос по Yii2 where()

Tags: yii2, activerecord

У меня в таблице БД есть запись массива c ID(categories_id), с использованием implode и выглядит он так: `25,43,56` (это String). Я пытаюсь вывести поля так `Model::find()->where(['categories_id' => $cat_id])->all()`. Но проблема в том что поиск не произойдет. Так как в этом случае вывести??? Спасиб)

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае допущена ошибка в проектировании и, скорее всего, данная проблема будет не единственной. Если есть возможность или проект новый (маленький), изучите [особенности работы со связанными данными в Yii2](https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-db-active-record.html#relational-data) и переделайте архитектуру БД.

Насколько понятно из вопроса, одна сущность может иметь несколько категорий. Для этого создайте промежуточную таблицу и привязывайте категории к сущности через нее.

Если же нет возможности провести рефакторинг, то можно (продолжать мучения) попробовать использовать LIKE в конструкции WHERE. Такой запрос будет более тяжелый.